# Create all possible combinations of elements

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, java-stream

I need to create all possible combinations of some kind of Key, that is composed from X (in my case, 8), equally important elements. So i came up with code like this:

```
final LinkedList<Key> keys = new LinkedList();

firstElementCreator.getApplicableElements() // All creators return a Set of elements
          .forEach( first -> secondElementCreator.getApplicableElements()
           .forEach( second -> thirdElementCreator.getApplicableElements()
            // ... more creators
           .forEach( X -> keys.add( new Key( first, second, third, ..., X ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) );

return keys;
```

and it's working, but there is X nested forEach and  i have feeling that i'm missing out an easier/better/more elegant solution. Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you need to an arbitrary number of loops, recursion is almost always the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it Cartesian Product? Many libraries provide the API, for example: [Sets](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html) and [Lists](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html) in Guava:

```
List<ApplicableElements> elementsList = Lists.newArrayList(firstElementCreator, secondElementCreator...).stream()
        .map(c -> c.getApplicableElements()).collect(toList());

List<Key> keys = Lists.cartesianProduct(elementsList).stream()
        .map(l -> new Key(l.get(0), l.get(1), l.get(2), l.get(3), l.get(4), l.get(5), l.get(6), l.get(7))).collect(toList());
```

Comment: This is an answer i was looking for. Still, this solution has a disadvantage: every of my Element has different type (now i see i didn't mention that), so type casting would be necessary. Maybe it's possible to create some common interface, i'll think about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of input sets is fixed (it has to match the number of arguments in the Key constructor), your solution is actually not bad.

It's more efficient and easier to read without the lambdas, though, like:

```
for (Element first : firstElementCreator.getApplicableElements()) {
    for (Element second : secondElementCreator.getApplicableElements()) {
        for (Element third : thirdElementCreator.getApplicableElements()) {
            keys.add(new Key(first, second, third));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, streams aren't always the best solution, this definitely looks better, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical solution is to use `flatMap`. However, the tricky part is to create the `Key` object from the multiple input levels.

The straight-forward approach is to do the evaluation in the innermost function, where every value is in scope

```
final List<Key> keys = firstElementCreator.getApplicableElements().stream()
  .flatMap(first -> secondElementCreator.getApplicableElements().stream()
    .flatMap(second -> thirdElementCreator.getApplicableElements().stream()
      // ... more creators
      .map( X -> new Key( first, second, third, ..., X ) ) ) )
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but this soon becomes impractical with deep nesting

A solution without deep nesting requires elements to hold intermediate compound values. E.g. if we define `Key` as

```
class Key {
    String[] data;
    Key(String... arg) {
        data=arg;
    }
    public Key add(String next) {
        int pos = data.length;
        String[] newData=Arrays.copyOf(data, pos+1);
        newData[pos]=next;
        return new Key(newData);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Key("+Arrays.toString(data)+')';
    }
}
```

(assuming `String` as element type), we can use

```
final List<Key> keys =
    firstElementCreator.getApplicableElements().stream().map(Key::new)
      .flatMap(e -> secondElementCreator.getApplicableElements().stream().map(e::add))
      .flatMap(e -> thirdElementCreator.getApplicableElements().stream().map(e::add))
      // ... more creators
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that these `flatMap` steps are now on the same level, i.e. not nested anymore. Also, all these steps are identical, only differing in the actual creator, which leads to the general solution supporting an arbitrary number of `Creator` instances.

```
List<Key> keys = Stream.of(firstElementCreator, secondElementCreator, thirdElementCreator
                           /* , and, some, more, if you like */)
    .map(creator -> (Function<Key,Stream<Key>>)
                    key -> creator.getApplicableElements().stream().map(key::add))
    .reduce(Stream::of, (f1,f2) -> key -> f1.apply(key).flatMap(f2))
    .apply(new Key())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here, every creator is mapping to the identical stream-producing function of the previous solution, then all are reduced to a single function combining each function with a `flatMap` step to the next one, and finally the resulting function is executed to get a stream, which is then collected to a `List`.